# How create new user with Firebase API w/o signing out?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

user signs in. I make a call to create new user with

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
```

it successfully creates new firebase user. Before this call `firebase.auth().currentUser.uid` gives different uid then after the call. So active user changes.

Is there any way for active user create another user and still be active user?

**I know one way to work this around**:

Save user's email & password to memory and after creating user re-login back to original user, but it requires saving password and i don't like it.

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(user => {
        // login back to main account
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(current_user_email, current_user_password).then(original_user => {

          const userRef = firebase.database().ref().child(`users/${user.uid}`);
          userRef.set({
            ...
```

Comment: Same question as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517208/firebase-kicks-out-current-user

Answer (score 1):

To add a new Firebase user without automatically switching to that user you can use a secondary Firebase instance to create the user. For example:

```
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "asdasdlkasjdlkadsj",
  authDomain: "asdfg-12345.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://asdfg-12345.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "asdfg-12345.appspot.com",
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);  // Intialise "firebase"
var fbAdmin = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig, "Secondary"); // Intialise "fbAdmin" as instance named "Secondary".
```

To create the user:

```
fbAdmin.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
 .then(function(newUser) {
  // Success. 
  // Log out.
  fbAdmin.auth().signOut()
   .then(function () {
    // Sign-out successful.
    console.log('fbAdmin signed out.');
  }, function (error) {
    // An error happened.
    console.log('Error siging out of fbAdmin.');
    console.log(error);
  });
}, function (error) {
  // There's a problem here.
  console.log(error.code);
  console.log(error.message);
})
```

The above is for plain JavaScript. It's a bit trickier if you're using [auto configuration](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/04/easier-configuration-for-firebase-on-web.html) to manage multiple environments. (See also [Reserved URLs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/reserved-urls)).

If you're using node.js you can use the [Firebase Admin Node.js SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users). For requirements and set up information see the [installation instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup).

**Edit:** Pretty much identical to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517208/firebase-kicks-out-current-user#38013551).