# Preventing authentication when creating a user via createUserWithEmailAndPassword

Tags: javascript, authentication, firebase, angularfire

I want the ability to create default accounts for users as well as setting up their information in the database. This means a user account needs to be created via auth with a username and passsword, and I need to create a new database entry with some basic info about that user.

However, calling `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` also authenticates you as that newly created user, which is not ideal. [Documentation Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#create_a_password-based_account)

How can I create users in my web app with `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` without it automatically authenticating me as the newly created user?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517208/firebase-kicks-out-current-user

Comment: Why can't you signOut that user?