# Firebase Admin Create User Programmatically?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

Is it possible for one Firebase user (setup as an admin in my own database) to create another user account?

I need to create an user management app that allows the admin to create and delete user accounts for the primary app.

Comment: When you create a user `createUserWithEmail:password:completion:`, that user is automatically logged in. This unfortunately means that there is no good way to create users from an admin back-end. We're working on a solution, but as usual: I can't give any timelines or commitments.

Comment: Thank you Frank for your comment. Much appreciated. This would be a great and really helpful feature!

Comment: This seems to be a re-occurring theme. See this [Create user with v3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37730712/how-to-just-create-an-user-in-firebase-3-and-do-not-authenticate-it)