# Is there any way to delete a different user authentication programmatically in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am authenticated with my email programmatically (raphaelg9@gmail.com) and I am trying to delete another user (test@samsung.com) in Firebase also programmatically, but I could not find any way to delete a different user account using the native Firebase API.

I am trying to delete this user auth:
[different user auth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4W9fm.jpg)

Is it possible to do that?

Thank you

Comment: There is currently no administrative API for Firebase Authentication. We're working on it. But as usual: no promises or timelines. (Similar, but not the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37730712/how-to-just-create-an-user-in-firebase-3-and-do-not-authenticate-it)