# firebase createUser without signin

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

My admin user can create other users, but everytime I create a user my admin user is signed out and the new user is signed in automatically, is there any way to create user without signing in?

Comment: create user automatically signed in ... thtas how it behaves ... and I dont think there is any other way to create user without sign in

Comment: I actually found a way to get this working, take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38013551/4916627)

Comment: I just found it easier to run and URL to a firebase function that did all this