# Security about creating user by Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions

There are many [discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38005960/firebase-createuser-without-signin) about creating a user without sign the user in using Firebase Web SDK. I created a Cloud Function and used Admin SDK to create a user:

```
exports.createUser = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const param = request.body

  admin.auth().createUser({
    email: param.email,
    emailVerified: false,
    password: param.password,
  })
})
```

But in my angular2 app, I have to use HTTP to POST the email and password to Cloud Functions for Firebase. Is it safe to do this without encrypting the password?

Comment: is password saved encrypted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is safe. All Cloud Functions are served on https URLs which means that the contents are encrypted in transit. Do make sure that you are sending the request to `https://us-central1-<your_project>.cloudfunctions.net` and not `http`.