# Xcode Firebase get authenticated user while logged in as someone else

Tags: xcode, firebase, firebase-authentication

Anyone know how I can get the user id for a certain user in Auth?

Let's say I am logged in with current user jalla@gmail.com, then I can get userid by

```
let userId = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
```

But if I want to get the userId of the other user jarra@gmail.com while I am logged in as jalla@gmail.com.

How can I do that?

[image]

This is how I create a new user:

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: txtUsername.text!, password: txtPassword.text!, completion: {
            user, error in

            if error != nil {
                print("error: " + error.debugDescription)
            }
            else{
                print("User created")
                self.login()
            }
        })
```

Which result in the authenticated user in the image attached.

I also have a Users table, but this has nothing to do with authenticating users for login.

[image]

The thing is that I need to programatically add new authenticated users. Which is ok, but how can I query data from the Authenticated table? I need to do it because I add the authenticated uid to each user roots in the database (see User table image)

Comment: From firebase database

Comment: When you say *logged in as" do you mean in the Firebase console or in code?

Answer (score 0):

For each user, create a record in your Firebase Database and store `uid` for each user so that you can retrieve that `uid` once you need it.

If you will query `uid` information by using the email information of the said user (i.e. jarra@gmail.com in your case), it might be best to store user information including `uid` under a key of respective user's email.

Comment: Using email's as a key can lead to a whole slew of issues; email addresses change and if you are referring to users by their emails in other areas of the Firebase structure (which is common), that will break if a user email changes. It's best practice to separate dynamic data (like an email) from node keys, which must remain static - leveraging the Firebase assigned UID is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you are logging in code rather than the console, one option is to leverage a /users node.

With Firebase, it's common practice to have a /users node that stores information about your users.

```
users
  uid_001
    email: "dr@who.com"
    name:  "Dr. Who"
    fav_food: "Jelly Babies"
  uid_002
    email: "homer@simpsons.com"
    name: "Homer Simpson"
    fav_food: "Doughnuts"
```

The uid's used as the key to each user node are the ones created by Firebase when the user is created.

From there, it's a snap to query for the email address which will retrieve the node in question, the parent key being the uid of the user.

Comment: Yes, I have a users node like the one you have added. But the key of each subnode is the authenticated uid. So each time I create a new authenticated user programatically I need to get that new uid. To add in the subnode of the user node (like your uid_001 and did_002)

Comment: @TommyF Oh, you've discovered one of my issues with Firebase 3. Check out this answer and a brilliant workaround from Andre [Firebase kicks out current user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517208/firebase-kicks-out-current-user/38013551#38013551).  The thing to do is to use another firebase account to create the user and then grab their uid so you can create the node in the /users node.

Comment: That looks interesting. But I can't figure out how to init a second account with swift. Do you know ;)

Comment: I do believe that is javascript

Comment: @TommyF Wow - yes it is, I just auto converted it in my brain. lol. What you need to do is to create a second FIRApp and then FIRAuth.authWithApp().