# Creating Users in AngularFire without Signing In

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

Im making an app in `AngularJS`, My App has a scenario that a user with Admin role can create users.

I know I can create users using

`$createUserWithEmailAndPassword("my@email.com", "mypassword")` but it Sign outs `current User`.

I want just to create users,not let them Sign in immediately after registering.

I found that I can use `Firebase Admin SDK` for it. But I unable to initialize it in my controller as it gives error `require is not defined`

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

    admin.initializeApp({
        serviceAccount: "/myservice.json",
        databaseURL: "URLDB"
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just [responded to your comment on a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517208/firebase-kicks-out-current-user/37614090?noredirect=1#comment68218148_37614090):

> The Firebase Admin node.js SDK should be run in a trusted environment only. Creating a user without signing them in is considered an administrative task.

You should not use the Firebase Admin SDK to add this functionality to the same app that you give to your regular users. It would be a security concern.

Comment: Oh Sorry I didn't notice your comment. So there is any other way to fulfil my requirement? My Client Admin wants to create accounts for his management

Comment: The workaround in the [accepted answer to the same question you commented](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38013551/209103) on will probably still work.

Comment: oh, initializing Secondary app? lemme try