# Firebase logs out current user when creating a new one

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I'm creating an iPhone app where an admin user can create new users, but as the Firebase documentation states **"If the new account was created, the user is signed in automatically"**, so I'm looking for a way to avoid signing in to that newly created user.

Is there any way I can avoid this without using the new Firebase Admin SDK (that is web only AFAIK)?

Comment: The Firebase Admin SDK is for running on a node.js server (that doesn't mean it is just for web). But if you want a client-side only approach, it indeed won't work. You might be able to try something similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517208/firebase-kicks-out-current-user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got [this Javascript smart workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38013551) working for iOS. Works flawlessly:

```
NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"GoogleService-Info" ofType:@"plist"];
FIROptions *secondaryAppOptions = [[FIROptions alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
[FIRApp configureWithName:@"Secondary" options:secondaryAppOptions];
FIRApp *secondaryApp = [FIRApp appNamed:@"Secondary"];
FIRAuth *secondaryAppAuth = [FIRAuth authWithApp:secondaryApp];

[secondaryAppAuth createUserWithEmail:user.email
                             password:user.password
                           completion:^(FIRUser * _Nullable user, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                                [secondaryAppAuth signOut:nil];
                          }];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this in multiple ways:

Option 1 : save the credentials of the admin user securely on your device. Then, when the user creates a new user, log in with the admin credentials. This will log you out and immediately log you back in.

Option 2 : use the admin sdk to create a user with a rest API call on the web side.

Comment: Thank you! I think that saving credentials on the device, even when doing it securely it's a little dangerous, and I don't have a web side as I'm using Firebase as my backend, but those two options would work.

Comment: Please give a tick for the right answer. Thank you in advance