# Firebase Android (Java) Create a new Account without logging it in

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication

I am going to develop a project with an Admin function. The question that I want to ask is how can I create a new Firebase account by using Firebase Authentication without signing the new account in while I have logged in the Admin account to create the new account. I do not want the admin account to be signed out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42040014/firebase-create-user-without-sign-in

Comment: What do you mean by "without signing the new account in while I have logged in the Admin account to create the new account."?

Comment: Ok it is like, Admin have to register an account for the staff. I have logged in the admin account, and then admin create an account for the staff. The account creation is done by the firebase function which is  createUserWithEmailAndPassword(). After the creation of the account it will auto login the new staff account created and log out the admin account which is currently signed in. So what I want is admin create the staff account without log in the staff account. @AlexMamo