# Firebase Auth Android, create user without sign in

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

How to create an user without sign in with Firebase Auth Android ?

It looks like the accepted solution here is a bit outdated : [Firebase create user without sign in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42040014/firebase-create-user-without-sign-in)

Nowadays, is there any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, answering myself after some research.

It looks like the situation is the same today. We still have to create an other instance of `FirebaseAuth` to avoid triggering auth state on the default `FirebaseAuth` instance you use.

But i suggest a simpler way to do it, without having to provide api key, application id...etc by hand by just using the `FirebaseOptions` of the default instance.

```kotlin
val firebaseDefaultApp = Firebase.auth.app
val signUpAppName = firebaseDefaultApp.name + "_signUp"

val signUpApp = try {
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(
        context,
        firebaseDefaultApp.options,
        signUpAppName
    )
} catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
    // IllegalStateException is throw if an app with the same name has already been initialized.
    FirebaseApp.getInstance(signUpAppName)
}

// Here is the instance you can use to sign up without triggering auth state on the default Firebase.auth
val signUpFirebaseAuth = Firebase.auth(signUpApp)
```

How to use ?

```kotlin
signUpFirebaseAuth
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                // Optional, you can send verification email here if you need

                // As soon as the sign up with sign in is over, we can sign out the current user
                firebaseAuthSignUp.signOut()
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                // Log
            }
```

Comment: If you have an alternative to the approach suggested in answers to the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517208/firebase-kicks-out-current-user) I linked, please post an answer to *that* question rather than posting a new duplicate question with your own answer.

Comment: This question is more about javascript, not Android. I don't find that so clear having to scroll to a not validated and not upvoted answer for Android.