# Firebase user PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

am using firebase authentication, I refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517208/firebase-kicks-out-current-user)

```
"users": {
        ".read": "auth != null && root.child('admins').child(auth.uid).val() == true",
        ".write": "auth != null && (root.child('admins').child(auth.uid).val() == true)",
        "$uid": {
          ".read": "auth != null && (auth.uid == $uid || root.child('admins').child(auth.uid).val() == true)",
          ".write": "auth != null && (auth.uid == $uid || root.child('admins').child(auth.uid).val() == true)"
        }
      },
```

This is my firebase user table rules.

my services.js

```
signupUser: function(newUser) {
          var secondaryApp = firebase.initializeApp(FirebaseAppConfig, "Secondary");
          var usersRef = firebase.database().ref().child('users');
          return secondaryApp.auth()
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(newUser.email, newUser.password)
          .then(function(firebaseUser) {
            secondaryApp.auth().signOut();

            var newUserWithoutPwd = _.extend({}, newUser);
            delete newUserWithoutPwd.password;
            return usersRef
            .child(firebaseUser.uid)
            .set(newUserWithoutPwd)
            .then(function() {
              return newUserWithoutPwd;
            });
          });
        },
```

Authendication is success. But user table show in permission denied error.

Show below screen shot

[image]

Comment: Based on what do you think that the user has permission to write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove `secondaryApp.auth().signOut();`
2. Update this `return firebase.database(secondaryApp).ref().child('users')`.

   ```
   signupUser: function(newUser) {
   var secondaryApp = firebase.initializeApp(FirebaseAppConfig, "Secondary");
   return secondaryApp.auth()
     .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(newUserInsert.email, newUserInsert.password)
     .then(function(firebaseUser) {
       var newUserWithoutPwd = _.extend({}, newUserInsert);
       delete newUserWithoutPwd.password;

       return firebase.database(secondaryApp).ref().child('users')
        .child(firebaseUser.uid)
        .set(newUserWithoutPwd)
        .then(function() {
      return newUserWithoutPwd;
      });
   });
   },
   ```

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you want the newly created user to write their user profile to the database. In that case it is important that:

1. you write the profile data *as* the current user: `firebase.database(secondaryApp).ref().child('users')`
2. you don't sign out the user, until the writing is completed

In code:

```
signupUser: function(newUser) {
      var secondaryApp = firebase.initializeApp(FirebaseAppConfig, "Secondary");
      var usersRef = secondaryApp.database().ref().child('users');
      return secondaryApp.auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(newUser.email, newUser.password)
      .then(function(firebaseUser) {
        var newUserWithoutPwd = _.extend({}, newUser);
        delete newUserWithoutPwd.password;
        return usersRef
          .child(firebaseUser.uid)
          .set(newUserWithoutPwd)
          .then(function() {
            secondaryApp.auth().signOut();
            return newUserWithoutPwd;
          });
      });
    },
```

Comment: Thanks. It's better.