# Creating fire base new user removing current user

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I have this issue where every time when create a new user account, it replace the current user that is already signed in.

Comment: you need to use `push()`

Comment: When you create a new user with the Firebase Android SDK, that user is immediately authenticated and any existing authentication session is terminated. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517208/firebase-kicks-out-current-user

Answer (score 0):

you should use push() method. Push is creating new id for every entry so data cannot be overwritten.