# Firebase: creating an account while I am already logged in

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I wanna create accounts while I am already logged in.
**For example :**
I'm logged in as an admin on a website and I wanna create accounts for drivers that work for me and save the uid (in a firebase collection with custom data) or something unique with what I could identify that **driver@admin.com** is created by **admin@gmail.com**.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to programmatically create accounts for other users, you'll have to use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) on a backend you control.  You won't be able to do this directly from within a mobile app.  You'll have to figure out some way to invoke your backend code from within your app.  (Explaining all your options here is out of the scope of a Stack Overflow question.)

Comment: I'm going to have to disagree with your statement _" You won't be able to do this directly from within a mobile app"_. Take a look at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38013551/4916627)