# How can I create a new user via Firebase Auth without signing in?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm working on an enterprise application in which administrators create new users (there is no sign-up form).  I am using Firebase Auth, which is great in many ways, but I've come across a problem for my use case.  When you use `firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)`, the user thereby created is automatically signed in.  This obviously won't work when an admin is creating the user accounts.  Is there any way to avoid this behavior? Thanks.

Comment: This is a good use case for the [Firebase Admin SDKs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/). Instead of creating the user client-side, you create the user in a managed environment, like a server or [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/). You have the client make a call to your endpoint when you want to add a new user. This [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-admin/#0) shows how to incorporate custom claims using the Firebase Admin Auth SDK. This is a little different from what you're doing, but it can get you started.

Comment: Sounds like an answer Jen! :)   If you can't use the Admin SDK, this is the only option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517208/firebase-kicks-out-current-user

Comment: @JenPerson Great idea.  I'll use the Admin SDKs.  Feel free to make your comment the answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Great! Let me know how the experience goes because we're always looking for new ways to improve documentation.

Comment: Already done and it worked great. If I didn’t just miss this option in the clientside docs, it might be a helpful cross-reference to include there for folks with this use case.

Comment: Another way is to store user information in the database like real time database.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a good use case for the [Firebase Admin SDKs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/). Instead of creating the user client-side, you create the user in a managed environment, like a server or [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/). You have the client make a call to your endpoint when you want to add a new user. This [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-admin/#0) shows how to incorporate custom claims using the Firebase Admin Auth SDK. This is a little different from what you're exactly looking for, but it can get you started in the right direction.

Comment: The mentioned codelab unfortunately does not exist anymore (404 - page not found).

Comment: Looks like this might be similar to what was originally in that codelab? https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims

Answer (score 0):

This answer helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54412713

In short, the idea is to create a temporary Firebase app and then dispose of it when you're done.

```
Future<UserCredential?> createFirebaseUserAsAdmin(String email, String password) async {
    UserCredential? userCredential;
    FirebaseApp app = await Firebase.initializeApp(
      name: 'Temp',
      options: firebaseOptions(EnvService.environment),
    );

    try {
      userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instanceFor(app: app).createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      // Do something with exception. This try/catch is here to make sure
      // that even if the user creation fails, app.delete() runs, if is not,
      // next time Firebase.initializeApp() will fail as the previous one was
      // not deleted.
    }

    await app.delete();
    return userCredential;
  }
```