# createUserWithEmailAndPassword automatically sign in

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm doing an APP that some user have permission to aprove/deny new users, but when I user createUserWithEmailAndPassword it auto log in the new user to device. Is there any way to only create withing siggin ' in?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create a new user via Firebase Auth without signing in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52433899/how-can-i-create-a-new-user-via-firebase-auth-without-signing-in)

Answer (score 0):

Not, this isn’t possible with firebase, you can get this behaviour with your own backend.