# How to create a user in firebase with a logged in user in web using javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am designing my web application using firebase in which the admin had to create the user accounts. I am using **createUserWithEmailandPassword** method to create the user acccounts.

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
.catch(function(error) {
});
```

But whenever i use this method to create an account the admin accounts gets signed out and is signed in with the newly created user account.

I don't want to be signed in with newly created account and should be continued with the old admin account. Please tell me an alternative for this.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users You should use the Admin SDk

Comment: Hi @Badgy i am not using node js in my project, just using javascript by importing from firebase cdn links .... infact if we use Node Js, there is a feature called as  admiin, by which my requirment can be achieved. Thanks for the answer

Comment: This is the expected behavior: the Firebase JavaScript SDK is meant to be used for signing in regular users, not for admin activities. If you can't use the Admin SDK that Badgy commented about, have a look at the answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517208/firebase-kicks-out-current-user, which are in line with what Badgy and Jack commented/answered.

Answer (score 0):

I initialise two apps for this need and make sure when creating accounts i use the second app. This way i can create the users and although the user gets logged into the new account its on the second firebase app so is isolated from the websites logic. More info on setting up [multiple apps here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#initialize_multiple_apps)

```
// Initialize the app
firebase.initializeApp(appConfig);

// Initialize another app with a same config
var createUserApp = firebase.initializeApp(appConfig, "createUserApp");

// You can then access the other app to create the user like this
createUserApp.firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
```

Your other option is to use the admin sdk.

Comment: Hi Jack Woodard, i am not using node js in my project, just using javascript by importing from firebase cdn links .... infact if we use Node Js, there is a feature called as  admiin, by which my requirment can be achieved. Thanks for the answer

Comment: No worries, both approaches will work, depends on the level of work you want to do as the example showed is very low effort from dev effort but implementing nodejs version on a server is more work but more scalable with bulk actions to create many users etc