# Create a user in firebase without login

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

there is some way to create a user on firebase without automatic login and firebase-admin? Something like:

```
auth.createUserAndRetrieveDataWithEmailAndPassword(cd.email,cd.senha).then(user => {
    console.log(user);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log("error");
  });
```

or

```
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(cd.email,cd.senha).then(user => {
    console.log(user);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log("error");
  });
```

Comment: You can use a second auth reference like I showed in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38013551/4916627). It will still log the user in but not on your main auth reference.

Comment: it works, appreciate!