# Firebase kicks out current user - "Managing users" with the web SDK

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I have a (not so small) project started with ReactJS and Firebase web SDK - and I would like to somehow manage (at least add & delete) users in my system.

1. I am totally aware, that there is an [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/client/libraries), but I wouldn't like to transition to that in the current phase of the development. I would like to go on with the web SDK.
2. I have seen this [nice workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517208/firebase-kicks-out-current-user) regarding the user-addition - and I managed to create & insert users with that.

Now, I need a way to delete or suspend users (at least), if possible. (I don't need strictly to have the update option, I can live without that.)

Do you now any way / workaround to that - similar to the point 2. ? Any idea how to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mobile and web clients for Firebase Authentication are not capable of changing the status of an arbitrary user account.  A user account only has permission to delete itself, not other accounts.

You will need to use the Admin SDK for that, from a backend or desktop system you control.  Initialized with a service account, it will have privileged access to [manage user accounts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users).