# How to avoid being signed in automatically when a new user is created using firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

What i am trying to do is allow users to create other accounts but the issue i ran into was when i create a user using createUserWithEmailAndPassword i automatically get signed in as the new user. so how do i avoid it.

I am trying to create user from admin panel where admin is registered. If i use the following code it login with new user data.

This is the code:

```
submit(){
    this.afAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.form.Eemail, this.password).then( res => {
        this.form.userid = res.user.uid;
        this.user.addnotice(this.form);
        this.cancel();
        this.succesToast();
    }, err =>{
        this.failToast();
    })
}
```

Comment: There is [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38013551/10182897) for this already posting you just need to signout after the process successfully completed.

Comment: @Ashish yea i did try that what happens is i get signed out completely even from the account i was previously signed in from

Comment: So you just want to make new user from admin panel ? Above question does not provide information about admin panel or any other.

Comment: @Ashish yea exactly

Comment: the admin should be able to create new users so that's what i am trying to do but the thing is when i make the account i just get signed in to the newly created account

Comment: Please read my answer this might help you

Comment: You have to use the admin SDK if you want to create users without getting signed in

Comment: The linked answer shows how to use two `FirebaseApp` instances to accomplish the use-case, although the better approach is to use the Admin SDK in a trusted environment and call that from your application code as Ashish also said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way provided for web development to create user without signin. Instead there is method to create user without sign-in in [Admin-SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user) which will solve your problem.

To access this function you have to use node.js in [firebase function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions).