# Exist a way to don't auto signIn with FirebaseAUTH?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

my current project use the firebase auth to create a user, but the user is registered by a actual user, and if after register the new user, the actual user get logout and i need refresh the page to make the signin with the first user.
Are there any way to after signUp, don't auto login?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code you have now and explain more specifically how it's not working the way you want.

Comment: I think you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517208/firebase-kicks-out-current-user