# creating multiple users without using firebase admin sdk

Tags: firebase, next.js, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

Are there any way on how to add or CRUD multiple users in firebase(authentication) without the firebase admin sdk?

I do have this [add user function](https://prnt.sc/XKmsmIrVwU8P)  in my web, however after of some research and google-ing, I found at that it needs to have a firebase admin sdk. Is firebase admin sdk is really necessary for doing this functions and are there any payment/billing when using it? Thanks

Any suggestions are appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to [create](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user) multiple users, which is considered an administrative operation. While you *could* do this with a client-side SDK (as shown in [Firebase kicks out current user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517208/firebase-kicks-out-current-user)), the recommended, idiomatic approach is to use a Firebase Admin SDK for this in a trusted environment (such as your development machine, a server that you control, or Cloud Functions/Cloud Run).

There is no cost to using the Admin SDK, as otherwise that would be indicated on the [Firebase pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) page.

Comment: Hi Puff, I am trying the one that you've linked ``Firebase kicks out current user`` and it always says that ``secondaryApp.auth()`` is not a function, I've tried doing what he did on it. I think I might not need the firebase-admin-sdk since all the ``createUsers`` are the only thing I need. Thanks

Comment: As discussed in that answer, using the Admin SDK is the recommended approach these days. But if you're having a hard time making your code work, I recommend opening anew question with a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of where you got stuck when you tried to apply the approach with a secondary app.